# iOS Calendar View - Feed from JSON, display details

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase

I would like to display a calendar in my iOS app, the calendar should take data from a JSON file (Firebase).
Example JSON:

```
{
   "startDate": 20170221,
   "Title": "CalendarTitle",
}
```

So I would like to display the CalenderTitle title on the date of startDate in the calendar, just like you would with Fullcalendar. The user can then select the day to reveal more details.

I have looked at mbcalenderkit, JTAppleCalendar and a few more; but none of them have any docs that suggest this is possible.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What DOCs you need? all of them have their example and instructions how to use, what are you looking for?

Comment: I would like to read docs that explain how to feed my JSON events in to the calendar. For example - http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JTAppleCalendar/6.1.2/ - although it is the full documentation, it mostly just lists the methods, it is not clear to me which one I need. DataSource for example only tells me this snippet: "The object that acts as the data source of the calendar view."

Comment: All the components are made for general purpose, you can always dig into the library and modify the things as per your need for example in `JTAppleCalendar` they have [init](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JTAppleCalendar/6.1.2/Structs/ConfigurationParameters.html#/s:FV15JTAppleCalendar23ConfigurationParameterscFT9startDateV10Foundation4Date7endDateS2_12numberOfRowsGSqSi_8calendarGSqVS1_8Calendar_15generateInDatesGSqOS_20InDateCellGeneration_16generateOutDatesGSqOS_21OutDateCellGeneration_14firstDayOfWeekGSqOS_10DaysOfWeek_19hasStrictBoundariesGSqSb__S0_) function which takes `startDate` as input

Comment: You can modify init function and add a Tittle that you need and customize things, you won't get everything readymade.

Comment: Thank you @iphonic, that should give me a starting point. I was surprised by the lack of tutorials compared to Fullcalander (tutorials on taking data from a JSON feed that is)

Comment: @CoderXYZ lack of tutorials :( ? JTAppleCalendar has the most >> [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JTAppleCalendar/6.1.2/) << and >> [Tutorials](https://patchthecode.github.io/) << available than any iOS calendar library on Github. If you need specific questions answered, open a request at >> [TheRepository](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) <<. I check my issues every 2 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// In loadView or viewDidLoad
let calendar = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 300))
    calendar.dataSource = self
   calendar.delegate = self
   view.addSubview(calendar)
   self.calendar = calendar
```

more detail here: https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

Comment: Thank you! I will read over the docs, but how does the code above allow me to load my own data?